# Working Android Studio project, but gradlew from command line misses out the assets

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, gradle, assets

I'm putting together a scripted build system for an Android project I normally build with Android Studio. It has NDK parts and also fixed assets. I can run ./gradlew assembleRelease and everything runs through fine and creates an APK, but it always misses out a zip file I have in src/main/assets. How do I get the build to include the asset file. This is the end of app/build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        debuggable false
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets'] }
}
productFlavors {
}
```

I'll repeat that when I build this in Android Studio, it correctly includes the asset file.

Any help much appreciated.